# What is a parameter signature in PHP?

Tags: php, parameters, signature

The PHP official documentation while explaining about **extends** under classes and objects section, it says:

```
"When overriding methods, the parameter signature should remain the same or PHP
will generate an E_STRICT level error. This does not apply to the constructor
which allows overriding with different parameters."
```

So I want to know, what a parameter signature is?

The **example** inside the documentation is the following:

```
<?php
class ExtendClass extends SimpleClass
{
    // Redefine the parent method
    function displayVar()
    {
        echo "Extending class\n";
        parent::displayVar();
    }
}

$extended = new ExtendClass();
$extended->displayVar();
?>
```

Official online [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Answer (score 9):

The parameter signature is simply the definition of parameters in the definition (signature) of a method. What is meant with the quoted text is, to use the same number (and type, which is not applicable in PHP) of parameter when overriding a method of a parent class.
A signature of a function/method is also referred to as a *head*. It contains the name and the parameters. The actual code of the function is called *body*.

```
function foo($arg1, $arg2) // signature
{
    // body
}
```

So for example if you have a method `foo($arg1, $arg2)` in a parent class, you can't override it in a extended class by defining a method `foo($arg)`.

Comment: doesn't matter what the doc says, it can be overridden exactly like that bro. Try it out.

Comment: @Raidenace then taht would be a different method and not an extension of the one in the parent class.

Comment: No. If you have a parent class with `function displayVar()`, and child class which has `function displayVar($x)` then calling `childObj->displayVar()` should call the parents `displayVar()` with no params, since according to you that is a different method. But that is not how PHP behaves.

Comment: @Raidenace, no it will trigger an error `Declaration of ChildClass::displayVar() should be compatible with that of SimpleClass::displayVar()`

Comment: did you try it? And also it should not trigger that error since, they are two signatures and hence two different functions, no?

Comment: I did. The question here is, did you?

Comment: Yup. Did it too. Maybe you should paste the code you are trying out?

Comment: I tried that example from viper-7 (still accessible trough archive.org) and it does not produce any warnings works just fine despite documentation, i have PHP v5.6.26. Is documentation out of date for this matter or its a bug?