# Can't pass array through function, error: string given

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am trying to send an array via a function, but I only get `Uncaught TypeError: Psr\Log\AbstractLogger::error(): Argument #2 ($context) must be of type array, string given, called in...`. I'm using [KLogger](https://github.com/katzgrau/KLogger) so I can log important stuff on my website and sometimes, putting stuff in an array would be quite useful sometimes.

Here's how everything looks like in my code:

```
function logger($string, Array $array, $type = 'info') {
    global $filename, $filename_get;    # these variables contains the filename and GET that the visitor are currently at

    $dir = '/destination/somewhere/on-the-server';
    if(!file_exists($dir)) {
        create_folder($dir);    # a function that creates a new folder if it doesn't exists
    }


    $logger = new Katzgrau\KLogger\Logger($dir);

    if($type == 'emergency') {
        $logger->emergency($string.' - '.$filename . ($filename_get == '-' ? null : '?'.$filename_get), (empty($array) ? $array : ''));
    } elseif($type == 'alert') {
        $logger->alert($string.' - '.$filename . ($filename_get == '-' ? null : '?'.$filename_get), (empty($array) ? $array : ''));
    } elseif($type == 'critical') {
        $logger->critical($string.' - '.$filename . ($filename_get == '-' ? null : '?'.$filename_get), (empty($array) ? $array : ''));
    } elseif($type == 'error') {
        $logger->error($string.' - '.$filename . ($filename_get == '-' ? null : '?'.$filename_get), (empty($array) ? $array : ''));
    } elseif($type == 'warning') {
        $logger->warning($string.' - '.$filename . ($filename_get == '-' ? null : '?'.$filename_get), (empty($array) ? $array : ''));
    } elseif($type == 'notice') {
        $logger->notice($string.' - '.$filename . ($filename_get == '-' ? null : '?'.$filename_get), (empty($array) ? $array : ''));
    } elseif($type == 'info') {
        $logger->info($string.' - '.$filename . ($filename_get == '-' ? null : '?'.$filename_get), (empty($array) ? $array : ''));
    } elseif($type == 'debug') {
        $logger->debug($string.' '.$filename . ($filename_get == '-' ? null : '?'.$filename_get), (empty($array) ? $array : ''));
    }
}

logger('regular string', [
    'test' => 'hi'
], 'error');
```

I've tried "everything"! `Array $array`, `&$array`, and `$array = []`. What have I missed? How can I solve this?

Comment: shouldn't it be `!empty($array) ? $array : ''` ?

Comment: You mean on line 1 in my code in my question? I tried, but I got this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "!", expecting variable in...`

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] before asking a question here. Your question is off-topic without it.

Comment: I can't make a minimal reproducible example here because KLogger requires composer. If I could make the reproducible example, I would.

Comment: Note that almost all of the code in the branches is duplicated, which makes errors more likely. For one, the log message in the 'debug' branch is slightly different (' ' as a separator, rather than ' - '). Assuming this is a mistake, there are two general techniques that can remove the repeated code: 1. calculate the arguments before the block and pass as variables 2. use a variable method name instead of the branches (`$logger->$type($string ...);`).

Comment: As for a minimal reproducible example, you don't need `Katzgrau\KLogger\Logger`. Instead, create & call a stub function with the same argument types.

Comment: I am so sorry for the missunderstanding, @evgenifotia. I am both hungry and tired. Gil did gave me the correct answer :)

Comment: In other words, the stub function can have the same [signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16219888/90527) as the `Katzgrau\KLogger\Logger` methods. You can simplify further, to the point that the stub only has an argument of type `Array`, and still get the error. Creating a minimal sample helps focus in on the exact issue, and often creating it will help you realize what's going on (and how to fix it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in your code. Your second parameter is `empty($array) ? $array : ''`.

If `$array` is empty you send the `$array`, but if it's not empty you send an empty string.

It probably should be like this `empty($array) ? [] : $array`.

Comment: Thank you :) I totally missed that one and only focused on line 1 of the code in my question.

Comment: We've all been there, more times than we want to admit.